# When is the normal bundle of a submanifold trivial when the submanifold and ambient manifold are both stably parallelizable?

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology

Let $S,M$ be manifolds which are stably parallelizable manifolds and suppose that $S \subset M$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$. When is the normal bundle of $S$ trivial? In particular, what is wrong with the following argument?

$\nu_S = TM|_S/TS \cong (TM|_S \oplus \underline{\mathbb{R}}^N)/(TS \oplus \underline{\mathbb{R}}^N)$ where $\underline{\mathbb{R}}^N$ is a trivial bundle of large enough rank so that both $TM$ and $TS$ are stabilized. So then, $\nu_S \cong \underline{\mathbb{R}}^{\dim M + N}/\underline{\mathbb{R}}^{\dim S + N} \cong \underline{\mathbb{R}}^{\dim M - \dim S}$ and hence, is trivial.

However, this argument must be faulty because Hsiang-Levine-Szczarba showed that there is a homotopy sphere $\Sigma^{16} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{29}$ which has non-trivial normal bundle. Homotopy spheres are stably parallelizable.

Comment: The error is similar to "If $H \cong H'$ then $G/H \cong G/H'$. If you want your argument to work, you need to formulate a compatibility condition for the two trivializations, but likely it will not extremely useful.

Comment: To echo Connor Malin's comment, the error is the claim that the quotient of a trivial bundle by a trivial subbundle is again trivial. For example, $T\mathbb{R}^3|_{S^2}$ is trivial and has a trivial line subbundle spanned by the outward pointing normal vector field of $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the quotient is isomorphic to $TS^2$ which is non-trivial.